# Chrome allocations profile: why memory consumption for handleEvent is so huge?

Tags: memory-management, google-chrome-devtools, v8, event-listener

To start with one might take a look at [this post](https://medium.com/@WebReflection/dom-handleevent-a-cross-platform-standard-since-year-2000-5bf17287fd38) on medium.com regarding ability to assign pojo as an event listener. The thing is that this object should have handleEvent method in order to be able to react on a certain event.
For example:

```
const handler = {handleEvent(e) {this[`on${e.type}`](e)}};
```

In the above mentioned post on medium.com author sends us to [benchmark](https://gist.github.com/WebReflection/5aaca727bc3b784d43be3704cf65abff), which was created exactly to demonstrate the fact, that usage of handleEvent basically takes O(1) memory overheads.
For example (not the actual benchmark):

```
const handlersQueue = [];

const masterHandler = {
    handleEvent(e) {
        this[`on${e.type}`](e)
    },
    onclick: function() {++this.counter},
    counter: 0
};

for (let i = 0; i < 1e4; i++) {
    const newHandler = Object.create(masterHandler);
    document.body.addEventListener('click', newHandler);
    handlersQueue.push(newHandler);
}

document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
```

In that case it is logical to assume, that all the event handlers are going to borrow handleEvent method from a prototype (masterHandler).
Author has created a little bit more sophisticated form of above mentioned example (take a look at DynamicHandler class), but overall idea stays the same.
On the contrary, allocations profile shows an enormous memory consumption by handleEvent function (**Chrome** Version **64.0.3282.186** (Official Build) (64-bit), MacOS High Sierra):
[image: weird memory consumption results]
The questions are:

- a) why this is happening?
- b) shouldn't usage of handleEvent for all event listeners cost us O(1) (basically SelfSize(bytes) of 0 bytes) and not O(n)?
- c) is it a sign of an issue either in ChromeDevTools or V8 themselves?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Egorov, can you, please, comment on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here. String concatenation, i.e. `'on' + e.type` in the original benchmark, or your template literal based alternative:

```
`on${e.type}`
```

causes (unsurprisingly?) a string to be created on every invocation. 3.3MB for 100,000 invocations is 33 bytes per iteration; the String "onclick" requires 32 bytes on the heap, so that explains most of it.

While this is not *particularly* efficient, those strings at least are short-lived, i.e. the garbage collector will get rid of them quickly. Unless you're taking allocation profiles, you probably won't even notice; on the other hand, if you ever end up chasing real memory consumption issues, getting rid of such noise on the profile might be worth it just for that reason.

If you want to save that overhead, you could simply rename the "onclick" function to "click" (and similar for any other events), so you don't need to muck with strings at all.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. Once we get rid of string concatenation an allocation profile shows a figures, which are reflecting author's original idea. There is one thing though. You mentioned about 100 000 invocations, but in the original benchmark we see only 10 000 invocations. Does that mean, that 3.3MB / 1e4 gives us 330 bytes (which is huge) per invocation? How did you calculated amount of memory required to store string 'onclick'?

Comment: The benchmark defines `var instances = 10000; var dispatches = 10;`, causing the event handler to be called 10,000 * 10 times. The memory consumption per string follows from V8's internal object definition: one pointer (=8 bytes on x64) for the hidden class, one for the length, one for the hash, and 8 bytes for 7 characters (rounded up to the next multiple of a pointer size for alignment reasons).

Comment: Got it.
Thanks.